# Core Plot, plotting scatterplot with json data.

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, core-plot

I am new to CorePlot and having a little trouble understanding "data source". I am sure that I have most likely misinterpreted some of the functions. Right now, I am trying to display the 2 json data I have already gotten and saved into `_soldarray` and `_datearray`.

example of the data received (as it is on nsLog):

```
_soldarray : {0, 0, 0, "62.69", "48.3", 81,}
_datearray : {("02/07/12", "02/10/12", "02/14/12", "02/11/12", "02/10/12", "02/12/12"}
```

and I have

```
CPTPlotDataSource methods
-(NSUInteger)numberOfRecordsForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot {
return [_soldarray count];
}

-(NSArray *)numberForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndexRange:(NSUInteger)index {

switch (fieldEnum) {
    case CPTScatterPlotFieldX:

        for (int i =0 ; 50;i++){
            return [_datearray objectAtIndex:i];
        }
        break;

    case CPTScatterPlotFieldY:
        for (int j =0 ; 50;j++){
            return [_soldarray objectAtIndex:j];
        }

        break;
}
return 0;
```

}

and as for configuration:

```
CPTGraph *graph = self.hostView.hostedGraph;
CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *) graph.defaultPlotSpace;
// 2 - Create the three plots
CPTScatterPlot *aaplPlot = [[CPTScatterPlot alloc] init];
aaplPlot.dataSource = self;
aaplPlot.identifier = _soldarray;
CPTColor *aaplColor = [CPTColor redColor];
[graph addPlot:aaplPlot toPlotSpace:plotSpace];
```

I tried changing datasource to the array but that does not work as well. Can someone point me to the right directions. I am having trouble understanding how plot.datasource and how `-(NSArray *)numberForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndexRange:(NSUInteger)` index works. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

`-numbersForPlot:field:recordIndexRange:` expects the datasource to return an array of values for the given field while `-numberForPlot:field:recordIndex:` returns one value at a time for the given index.

Assuming that the values in the arrays are `NSNumber` objects (or something else that responds to `-decimalValue` or `-doubleValue` like `NSString`), you can implement this either way.

```
-(NSNumber *)numberForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot
                     field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum
               recordIndex:(NSUInteger)idx
{
    switch (fieldEnum) {
        case CPTScatterPlotFieldX:
            return [_datearray objectAtIndex:idx];
            break;

        case CPTScatterPlotFieldY:
            return [_soldarray objectAtIndex:idx];
            break;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

or

```
-(NSArray *)numbersForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot
                     field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum
          recordIndexRange:(NSUInteger)indexRange
{
    switch (fieldEnum) {
        case CPTScatterPlotFieldX:
            return [_datearray subarrayWithRange:indexRange];
            break;

        case CPTScatterPlotFieldY:
            return [_soldarray subarrayWithRange:indexRange];
            break;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: hello, thanks for helping. it is still not graphing. do you think I have to convert my array into nsnumbers??

Comment: i have also have
CPTScatterPlot *aaplPlot = [[CPTScatterPlot alloc] init];
 aaplPlot.dataSource = self;
 aaplPlot.identifier = _soldarray;

i am not sure if the identifier should be the array, because i am not sure what the identifier and datasource actually do

Comment: The `identifier` can be pretty much any object, although strings and numbers are the most common. It is used to uniquely identify a plot in the datasource and/or delegate when you are using the same one for more than one plot. If your graph only has one plot, the `identifier` is optional.

Comment: The values returned from the datasource, either singly or in arrays, need to be numbers or `[NSNull null]` to indicate missing values. The *Plot Gallery* example app includes a demo plot that uses dates along one axis. Core Plot includes a couple of custom formatters that make working with dates a little easier.

Comment: Thank you @eric for clarifying. I've implemented your first method. However, the graph still does not appear. I can't think of any other problems except wrong data format, because if I create an array such as:

Comment: [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:1],
                [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:2],
                [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:3],
                [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:3],
                [NSDecimalNumber numberWithFloat:3],
                nil];

Comment: it will graph out fine. so I do not know why the json array is not graphing.

Comment: You have to convert the JSON string into numbers that Core Plot understands.

Comment: Thank you. I got it to work now! I just need to format the date. again, big thanks!

Comment: @EricSkroch thanks for this very helpful info. Looking over the docs for CorePlot I still can't seem to find this information (looking here:   http://core-plot.github.io/iOS/interface_c_p_t_scatter_plot.html). Is there a system to the docs?

Comment: The plot datasource methods are part of the [`<CPTPlotDataSource>` protocol](http://core-plot.github.io/iOS/protocol_c_p_t_plot_data_source-p.html). The various plot types have their own datasource protocols that inherit from this one to provide data specific to the plot type.